# Allows automatic vCard attachment to every email from exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, vcf-vcard

I Have requirement to send vcard on exchange server level by preparing the vcard there itself and attach it in exchange server itself, is there any option available to create vcard file in exchange server. Any suggestions? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Transport Agent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877026(v=exchg.150).aspx that could do that eg Transport Agent catch Message why they are in the Transport Pipeline.

Cheers
Glen